# How to read CDATA from HTML tags

Tags: php, html, function

Following is the function in php which accepts any string(string will contain html tags as well) and return just a few words from that which is mentioned in the variable $min.

```
function gen_string($string,$min=500,$clean=true) {

    $text = trim(strip_tags($string));

        if(strlen($text)>$min) {
            $blank = strpos($text,' ');
            if($blank) {
                # limit plus last word
                $extra = strpos(substr($text,$min),' ');
                $max = $min+$extra;
                $r = substr($text,0,$max);
                $query = "select distinct ID from cms_content";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                $IDlink = 'http://localhost/www/index.php?ID='.$result;
                    if(strlen($text)>=$max && !$clean) $r=trim($r,'.') ;

            } else {
                # if there are no spaces
                $r = substr($text,0,$min).'.........';
            }

        } else {
            # if original length is lower than limit
            $r = $text;
        }
        return trim($r);
}
```

But the problem is that in the returned string, it does not read the html tags.
So how to make this function read the html tags so that the returned string must be in the formatted html tags?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
$text = trim(strip_tags($string));
```

[`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags) will remove all the tags, so that the function cannot possibly return any.

Since you are cutting out parts of the string, you will end up with non-valid HTML snippets. You need either [`tidy`](http://php.net/tidy) or [`HTMLPurifier`](http://www.google.com/search?q=HTMLPurifier) to fix this afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use [tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairstring.php) to construct a valid (x)html string, parse it into a [DOM document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php), then use the [XPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) (untested) `//body//text()`.

I've pointed you to the right functions/class methods, so you can hit the ground running.

The documentation and the user notes could be especially useful to you.

POC:

```
 1  <?php
 2  $string = '<p>Hello <b>World <i>out</i><span>there</span></b></p>';
 3  
 4  $string = tidy_repair_string($string);
 5  
 6  $doc = new DOMDocument;
 7  $doc->loadHTML($string);
 8  
 9  $path = new DOMXPath($doc);
10  
11  $entries = $path->query('//body//text()');
12  
13  $string = NULL;
14  
15  foreach($entries as $entry) {
16      if(preg_match('/\w/', $entry->nodeValue)) {
17          $string .= $entry->nodeValue;
18      }
19  }
20  echo $string;
```

Output: `Hello World outthere`.

Comment: I tried to make fit the documentation example in my function but could not get this...:(

Comment: I tried this also but not working http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/truncate-strings/

Comment: Well, my answer suggests that you rewrite your function in this new way.